# Write all array value to text file

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table

I make an array with math.random code:

```
i=1
x={}
while i<10 do
x[(i)] = math.random(1,999)
i=i+1
end
```

I want want to save all the value to a txt file that look like:
588,847,198,7748.
How can I do that
I using qlua for Android?

Comment: You can use `table.concat(x,',')` to combine all table entries in a single line with values separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

```
i=1 
x={} 
while i<10 do 
x[i] = math.random(1,999) 
i=i+1 
end

str = ""
for i,v in pairs(x) do
str = str .. v .. ","
end
saveString(str)
```

By the way, you don't have to write x[(i)], simply writing x[i] is already correct.

Comment: Thank you very much